# jspm does not transpile code from ES6 to ES5

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, traceur, jspm

Running `jspm bundle-sfx some/input some/output.js` does not transpile my code from ES6 to ES5. This makes the output file unusable.

Example contents of input file:

```
[1,2,3,4].map((i)=>i*i);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained by jspm author [here](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/478#issuecomment-73032169):

> ES6 transpilation only happens for ES6 modules, not ES6 files written in CommonJS.

It means that transpilation happens only for files using module syntax (`import`, `export`). It can be forced though by adding `"format es6";` at the top of the source file as so:

```
"format es6";
[1,2,3,4].map((i)=>i*i);
```

Comment: Btw, you can avoid parenthesis around `i`.

Comment: It can also be done with an override:

``
jspm install repo -o { format: 'es6' }
``

https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/478#issuecomment-73054638