# enable ES2015 default parameters with Babel and JSPM

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jspm

I'm setting up JSPM / Babel for the first time, and trying out a few ES6 features.

It seems only certain features work with the default transform, so I've tried to enable the ES2015 preset, using both package.json and the .babelrc file, as below:

```
"presets": ["es2015"]
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'm trying to add a default parameter to a function, so want to replace the following function

```
exports.width = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = x;
    return this;
};
```

with

```
exports.width = function(x = width) {
    width = x;
    return this;
};
```

I keep getting a  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` error however.

I've installed the preset `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`, as well as trying to install the individual plugin, but no dice.

Comment: This works for me using babel `6.2.0`. Can you verify your version of babel and try `babel filename.js --presets es2015`?

Comment: yep, its 5.8.34, and the babel command works fine. I answered my own question with a bit more digging, see below. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so it seems [JSPM will only transpile ES6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720963/jspm-does-not-transpile-code-from-es6-to-es5), so you need to pass a flag to any non ES6 modules to force it to transpile, so `"format es6";` at the top of the file.

Which is odd as it was transpiling the lambda `=>` functions but not the default params.